# Favicon doesn't show on slack link preview

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web

[image]

I have this issue where the favicon doesn't show in the link preview when sharing the link via slack (I imagine the same when sharing it via all social media)

I have this code `<link rel="icon" type= "image/png" href="<%= VUE_APP_DYNAMIC_FAVICON %>">` in the `index.html` file. which dynamically reads the favicon and correctly displays it in the browser.

The favicon shows in the browser if I navigate to the url, I am wondering how to get it to show in the preview.

Comment: Anything done dynamically in JS won't be picked up by Slack's link previews (nor most others; Facebook, Twitter, etc. won't see it, either.)

Comment: It would be that Vue dynamically loads the favicon with JS but JS does not run in the applied context (Slack preview link)

Comment: @ayagoub Can you please post the answer if you find it? i am also facing the same issue and I am looking for the solution